# Date aging calculator

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

I am trying to create two fields in Microsoft Word. One that has a  "created Date" (that I can manually enter) and the second that calculates the difference in days from created date to today's current day. It is to allow me to see how long an item has been worked on as I am using trying to build a schedule in word.

I am assuming a Macro needs to be created but I can't find any clear examples anywhere.
Thanks for your help

Comment: This site might have what you're looking for http://www.addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm

Comment: Depending on what you use for a "field" Word can do calculations using field codes. Try asking this in an end-user forum, first, such as Super User. Note that if a macro is required *form fields* can be linked to a macro to perform the calcuation.

Comment: To see how to do this and just about everything else you might want to do with dates in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html 
or:
http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party
In particular, look at the items titled *Calculate the # Days Difference Between Two Dates* and *Calculate the # Years Months & Days Difference Between Two Dates*. Do read the document's introductory material.